# What is the approximation to the probability a mouse has weight less than 8?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose the weight of mice is normally distributed with mean 10 and standard deviation 2. What is the approximation to the probability a mouse has weight less than 8?

I am looking to see the process how to solve this problem using the 68-95-99.7 stats rule. So far I have P(x<8) and 2 standard deviations from the mean would be .95 How would I put this in the mathematical form to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $2$ is the value of *one* standard deviation.

So, there is a $0.68$ probability that a mouse has a weight between $8$ and $12$ grams, and thus there is a $0.32$ probability that the weight of a mouse is outside that interval, i.e. below $8$ or above $12$. By symmetry, this means that there is a $0.16$ probability it is below $8$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you mind explaining me this: "there is a 0.32 probability that the weight of a mouse is outside that interval, i.e. below 8 or above 12" . Does it mean that there is 0.16 probability it is below 8 and 0.16 probability it is above 12?

Comment: @julian Yes, if you assume the distribution is symmetrical, then the probability of being below 8 is the same as the probability of being above 12, so given that the sum of those two probabilities is 0.32, they are each 0.16

Comment: thanks again. And one last thing. How can you tell it's one standard deviation and not two in this case?

Comment: @julian When it says 'mean 10 and standard deviation 2' I think it is pretty clear they mean one standard deviation ... if they had meant two or three devitions they would have been explicit about that.

Answer (score 1):

This is only **one** standard deviation away from the mean.

Using the 68-95-99.7 rule, you can find $P[8\leq X \leq 12]$.

Which complement to 1 is $P[X<8$ or $X>12]$.

Using the symetry of normal distribution, you finally divide by 2 to find $P[X<8]$